# Update table new column with values from another table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, copy, multiple-columns

I have two tables **table1** and **table2**.
I'm doing some changes and I realized that **table2** is not needed, but this table has lots of data already and I need to pass the values of **ID_B** from **table2** to **table1**.

Here's the structure:

## table1

```
 ID_table1 |  ID_table2 | ID_B      
  1        |   1        |    
  2        |   3        |    
  3        |   1        |    
  4        |   2        |
```

## table2

```
 ID_table2 |    ID_B  
  1        |     14  
  2        |     26  
  3        |     26
```

So what I want is the MySQL query to pass the **ID_B** value from **table2** to **table1** when the **ID_table2** on **table1** is equal to the **ID_table2** on **table2**.

For example, the row on **table1** where the **ID_table1** is 1 would have the **ID_B** = 14.

Can you help me on this?
Thanks in advance,

Miguel.

Comment: Could such a simple request be expressed in a more confusing way?

Comment: I tried my best to explain the situation, I was just afraid to left some important information out. Maybe that's why it got more confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JOINs you can do as.

```
update table1 t1
inner join 
table2 t2 on t2.ID_table2 = t1.ID_table2
set t1.ID_B = t2.ID_B
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c33f/1)**

Comment: Thanks this worked!  The fiddle was also a nice touch too, thanks for your time. All the Best.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like so:

```
UPDATE
  table1 AS target,
  (SELECT ID_table2, ID_B FROM table2) AS source
SET
  target.ID_B = source.ID_B
WHERE
  target.ID_TABLE2 = source.ID_table2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried this one too and it worked. Using "target" a "source" also helps understanding the solution. Thanks for your time :) All the best!